# iOS Learning with Lynda: Getting error can't invoke 'init' with argument of type @lvalue String

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

I'm trying to follow [lynda's](https://www.lynda.com/iOS-tutorials/Controlling-when-tapped-numbers-should-appear-calculator/415363/448627-4.html?) (not sure if nonmembers can see it) tutorial on iOS 9 and Swift, but I'm getting an error that doesn't match the screencast. If anyone's familiar, this is the tutorial: "Controlling when tapped numbers should not appear in the calculator"

This is a basic calculator that I'm trying to build. The basic idea is to take number inside a label into a string and then convert back into an number and then putting it back into a string so when pressing the button "0" it won't have multiple zeros on the calculator.

```
func updateText() {
    let labelInt:Int = Int(labelString)
    --> Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument of type '@lvalue String'
    label.text = "\(labelInt)"
}
```

in the screencast the error is different:

```
func updateText() {
    let labelInt:Int = Int(labelString)
    --> Value of optional type 'int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
    label.text = "\(labelInt)"
}
```

EDIT: Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Where does `labelString` come from?

Comment: @jtbandes I added a screenshot of the code

Comment: How about adding the code itself? :)

Comment: Also, what version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: I did a screenshot just so people can see the error. I'm using xcode 6.1, is that the issue?

Comment: Quite possibly. I recommend updating to 7 (I think the latest is 7.3).

Comment: Oh! Okay, yeah! let me try!! Thank, i'll come back once its finished and seeing if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unwrapped the `labelString` value with `!` sign, so write like,

```
func updateText() {
    let labelInt:Int = Int(labelString)!
    label.text = "\(labelInt)"
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: But my issue is, I'm not getting the same error like the screencase. I'm getting the `@lvalue String` error

Comment: As discuss in above comment, please check it with latest Xcode, Because i have tested it with Xcode 7.2 and its working fine.

Comment: blah! I tried to update my xcode from app store but my xcode is still at version 6.1. I even restarted my computer. Any ideas?

Comment: yeah.. you need to download it and then install if it won't update

Comment: oh, now it says that I need 10.11 OSX to install the Xcode 7. However, I'm seeing a lot of 1 star reviews for 10.11, scared to upgrade, but I guess I'll have to in order to use Xcode 7 huh?

Comment: Yup, updating to version 7+ is the culprit. If you want to update your answer, I can mark it.

Comment: Let me inform once you finish it and make it work succuessfully